# Can a class property be both T or IEnumerable<T>?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

Is there a way for a property in a class to accept both `T` or `IEnumerable<T>` as it's value?

I'm trying to implement a DTO for an API Success Response, where the property `Data` can both be a single JSON Object or a collection of JSON Objects. Is there a way to use one single class to achieve this or do I need to have two classes, one for `T` and other for `IEnumerable<T>`?

Here's my code:

```
public class ApiClass<T> where T : class, IEnumerable<T>
{
    public ApiClass(IEnumerable<T> data)
    {
        Data = data;
        Message = "Enumerable data received";
    }

    public ApiClass(T data)
    {
        Data = data;
        Message = "Object data received";
    }

    private IEnumerable<T> Data { get; set; }

    private string Message{ get; set; }
}
```

And that's the result I intend to have, after serializing an instance of the object:

```
{
  "data": {
    "Id": 1,
    "Name": "John"
  },
  "message": "Object data received."
}
```

or

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "Id": 1,
      "Name": "John"
    },
    {
      "Id": 2,
      "Name": "Mary"
    }
  ],
  "message": "Object data received."
}
```

This code compiles, however I get the following error message when I try to create an new object as in `return new ApiClass<User>(new User());`:

`Error: CS0311 - The type 'XPTO.User' cannot be used as type parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'ApiClass<T>'. There is no implicit reference conversion from 'XPTO.User' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<XPTO.User>'.`

Comment: Change line 11 to: Data = new T[] { data };

Comment: As someone who had to work with an API like this, I'd say "please don't". Is there a specific reason to not always use a collection for that property?

Comment: @Max That would result in a Json array of 1 item where as the OP wants data to be the single object in that case and not an array.

Comment: Error message seems pretty clear to me: your `XPTO.User` type doesn't implement `IEnumerable<XPTO.User>`. So naturally, you can't use that type as the type parameter for `ApiClass<T>`. It's certainly legal in C# for a type `T` to implement `IEnumerable<T>` (rare, but legal). But if that's the constraint you're going to impose, the type has to satisfy that constraint. Note that in any case, the property will still be serialized as a collection, not a single instance, because _that's the type of the property_.

Comment: @Max did some adjustments in the code and it did the trick. However I guess I should create separate classes to both avoid the client always picking the first on single items as ryanman pointed, and because I have no reason at all to use a single class, as tieson-t pointed too.

Comment: @TiesonT., no, no reason at all. I was wondering if there was a way for doing this and it sounded like a good idea, but now I see it's not.

Comment: @PeterDuniho thanks for the explanation. Now I can understand the error message.

Comment: @JonasLima maybe you don't need any of those classes, .net is pretty good, I usually just return whatever and it'll be serialized to JSON. Read more here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/action-return-types?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use multiple classes and let the programmer decide which to inherit from based on the return they need. For example:

```
public class ApiClass
{
    public string Message{ get; private set; }
}

public class ApiClass<T> : ApiClass where T : class
{
    public ApiClass(T data)
    {
        Data = data;
        Message = "Object data received";
    }

    public T Data { get; private set; }
}

public class ArrayApiClass<T> : ApiClass where T : class
{
    public ArrayApiClass(IEnumerable<T> data)
    {
        Data = data;
        Message = "Enumerable data received";
    }

    public IEnumerable<T> Data { get; private set; }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe there's a way to do this. As someone who would potentially consume an API, you do NOT want people to guess if their data is an array or not!

Instead, have a property called "MainData" or something if there's no collection. Otherwise people would much rather just get the first element in an array if there's a contract to always have a collection.